# How to keep an active link in nav list (twitter bootstrap)?

Tags: jquery, symfony, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to show an active link when the link is clicked (and that link stay active while the user is on link1 for example) (I'm using Symfony2 with Twitter bootstrap)

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="active"> <a href="/link1">Link</a> </li>
  <li class=""> <a href="/link2">Link</a> </li>
  <li class=""> <a href="/link3">Link</a> </li>        
</ul>
```

**EDIT**
The template of the menu is imported in each page as a block (I'm using twig), for example for link1.html.twig, I would have :
{% include menu.html.twig %}

code html ...

etc

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do the links go to separate pages? or sections on the same page?

Comment: Yes the links go to separate pages. So the page is refresh for each link.

Answer (score 3):

This should work :)

**JQuery**

```
var x = $(location).attr('href').replace( 'http://yourdomain.com' , ""); // Step 1
$('a[href="' + x + '"]').addClass('active'); // Step 2
```

**Edit**

Explanation

(Step 1) Pretty much you are capturing the full url and page name in the x variable 'http://yourdomain.com/page.html', deleting the domain name 'http://yourdomain.com' leaving you with '/page.html'

(Step 2) Match the  link that has the value '/page.html' and add the class 'active' to it

Comment: For the demo case provided by @Reveclaire this should work and is a neat solution. However it may be worth explaining it in a little detail.

Comment: Thanks Lavabeams! I added an explanation, hope this helps! :)

Comment: This would work best when you use an include to populate your menus...don't have to mess with the menu on each and every page.

Comment: The active class needs to go on the li not the a, so the second line should be something like: $('a[href="' + x + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');

Comment: It seems dirty to do this in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming on each page you have your navigation elements. You just need to change which element has the class of "active".

**Link1** active as this is Link1.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="active"> <a href="/link1">Link</a> </li>
  <li class=""> <a href="/link2">Link</a> </li>
  <li class=""> <a href="/link3">Link</a> </li>        
</ul>
```

**Link2** active as this is Link2.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class=""> <a href="/link1">Link</a> </li>
  <li class="active"> <a href="/link2">Link</a> </li>
  <li class=""> <a href="/link3">Link</a> </li>        
</ul>
```

If you are doing something more complex than just going to the new page please update your question and explain as your question is a tad vague, otherwise the above should work.

Comment: @VlDesignz answer is probably suited to you. Just ensure you wrap it in a document ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

One `POCSS` ( Plain Ol' CSS ) way to do this:

In your `main.twig` file

```
<body class="{% block body_class 'home' %}">
<!-- stuff here -->
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="nav-home"> <a href="/">Link</a>Home</li>
  <li class="nav-about"> <a href="/about">About Us</a> </li>
  <li class="nav-contact"> <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a> </li>        
</ul>
```

In `about_page.twig` template

```
{% block body_class 'page-about' %}
```

In your `CSS` file

```
.page-about .nav-about, .page-home .nav-home, .page-contact .nav-contact {
  /* Active styles here */
}
```

The advantage of doing it this is that you can set other things on your pages as per that body class setting, like:

```
.page-about a { h1: green; }
.page-home a { h1: blue; }
.page-contact a { h1 : pink; }
```