# Changing Menu items, when going to a specific section of the site, is off by one section and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

This is a new question, based off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365472/changing-menu-options-is-not-changing-the-active-class-even-though-i-followed-th/71365659) which was nicely resolved.

Here's the [temp site](http://wtr2022.webparity.net/index.html) which I'm creating for the client. Here's [how this all originated](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-active-class-to-nav-menu-from-bootstrap/).

That all being said, however, when you scroll to or click on PROJECT, you'll be scrolled to the completed projects section. This is good.

[image: Projects Section]

However, when you click or SCROLL to Blog, Roofing or Contact, the targeting is off.

Blog is not active but Roofing is and so on for Roofing and Contact.

[image: Targeting off for menu to Section]

So, I don't understand when you scroll past or into or click to Blog, Roofing and Contact, the Active feature is off kilter.  @kmoser helped with my previous question and I didn't want to turn it into a discussion so I made a new question. Thank you everyone.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ftco_navbar bg-dark ftco-navbar-light sticky-top" id="ftco-navbar">
  <div class="container">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ftco-nav" aria-controls="ftco-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="fa fa-bars"></span> Menu
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#aboutus" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#serviceslink" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#projectslink" class="nav-link">Project</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#bloglink" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#roofinglink" class="nav-link">Roofing</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contactlink" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <img src="images/logos/weathertight-logo.png" class="logosmaller" alt="" />
        <!-- <span class="flaticon-roof-2"></span> -->
      </div>

      <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
        <div class="social-media">
          <p class="mb-0 d-flex">
            <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span class="fa fa-facebook"><i class="sr-only">Facebook</i></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span class="fa fa-twitter"><i class="sr-only">Twitter</i></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span class="fa fa-instagram"><i class="sr-only">Instagram</i></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span class="fa fa-dribbble"><i class="sr-only">Dribbble</i></span></a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<section id="bloglink" class="ftco-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center pb-5 mb-3">
      <div class="col-md-7 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
        <span class="subheading">News &amp; Blog</span>
        <h2>Latest news from our blog</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="roofinglink" class="ftco-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center pb-5 mb-3">
      <div class="col-md-12 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
        <span class="subheading">Roofing</span>
        <h2>Roofing that Pays for Itself</h2>
        <div class="sec-title text-center wow animated fadeInDown">
          <h2>Commercial Roofing that Pays for Itself!</h2>
          <p>The heating and AC loss you have been experiencing in your commercial building can be significantly reduced with one of our energy saving roofing systems! WeatherTight Systems’ completely air-tight roofing systems seal in your building’s cool
            air and heat. For most of our flat top roofing materials we also apply a seamless, high-solids silicone and acrylic based material as a way of ensuring there will be no water leaks into your commercial building. The result is a roof that is
            truly protected from the scorching sun and other destructive weather elements.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="contactlink" class="ftco-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            Contact link section
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth it to try out Bootstrap's own built-in Scrollspy solution: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/scrollspy/

Comment: I fixed it. Check it out:  http://wtr2022.webparity.net/index.html - What it was, was there is a TESTIMONIAL section. I commented it out. That was throwing off everything. I don't know but it was.